# Image in between a paragraph Using iText

Tags: java, image, text, itext

I am using iText to generate my custom .pdf document. I tried a lot but i am not able to do get a desired design of my text which includes an image. I need an output just like shown below:

[image]

I have tried Chunk class and Paragraph class but i am not able to get the desired. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have (at least) two options:

1. Use `image.setAlignment(Image.LEFT | Image.TEXTWRAP);` and add the image to the document (not to a `Chunk` or `Paragraph`). This will add the image to the left and wrap the other text around it.
2. Add the image at an absolute position, and add the text using `ColumnText` for *irregular columns*: http://1t3xt.be/?0b3

1 is the easiest way, but the result may not always be what you desire (you can tweak some things, such as adding a borden); 2 demands more work, but allows you to create the output exactly the way you want to.

Comment: +1. I think [***Movie Posters3***](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=51) example too is helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bruno and Ravinder. It totally worked out for me.