# Image on right side of page with text wrapping around it

Tags: c#, pdf, alignment, itext, word-wrap

Is there any way to align 2 or 3 pictures to right of the page and have a text around it (if the paragraph has space in the right side it should make use of the full length before wrapping to the next line)?

I also need to add to right side a table below the image.

The page should look something like this:

First example:

```
text text text  ------------
text text text  |   image  |
text text text  ------------
text text text  ------------
text text text  |   image  |
text text text  ------------
text text text text text text
```

Second example:

```
text text text  ------------
text text text  |   image  |
text text text  ------------
text text text  ------------
text text text  |   table  |
text text text  ------------
text text text text text text
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image in between a paragraph Using iText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030250/image-in-between-a-paragraph-using-itext)

Comment: In my case I need to position the image to the right, and I have to add more than one and a table at the end.

Comment: I think the only way that you're going to be able to accomplish this is to use the second option that Bruno mentioned in @AlexisPigeon's link, irregular columns and `ColumnText`. You'll need to measure the height of the table, [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7601244/231316) for some code for doing that.